# Internal Server Error on Post Request Spring Boot [Java]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to send a post request to add an User object to the list of users (no database).
getUser, getAllUsers Api endpoints are working fine and giving desired results.

When I send a Post request with User, it is always giving 500 Internal Server Error.

I have also printed out the User and data is fine.

Below is my code -

User Entity (User.java) -

```
public class User {

    
    private Integer userId;
    
    private String name;
    private String email;
    
    private Account account;
```

Getters and Setters along with constructors are also there.

My User Service and its implementation -

UserService.java -

```
@Service
public interface UserService {
    public User getUser(Integer userId);
    public List<User> getAllUsers();
    <T> ResponseEntity<T> deleteUser(Integer userId);
    <T> ResponseEntity<User> addUser(User user);
    
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
    List<User> userList = List.of(
            new User(1311, "Vaibhav Shrivastava", "innomightmail@gmail.com"),
            new User(1312, "Varun Shrivastava", "varun@gmail.com"),
            new User(1313, "Rajesh Shrivastava", "rajesh@gmail.com")
        );
    
    @Override
    public User getUser(Integer id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(this.userList.stream().filter(user -> user.getUserId().equals(id)).findAny().orElse(null));
        return this.userList.stream().filter(user -> user.getUserId().equals(id)).findAny().orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userList;
    }

    
    @Override
    public <T> ResponseEntity<User> addUser(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        userList.add(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>((User)user, HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
```

Controller (UserController.java) -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@GetMapping("/{userId}")
public User getUser(@PathVariable("userId") Integer userId) {
    User user = this.userService.getUser(userId);
    Account account = this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://account-service/account/user/" + user.getUserId(), Account.class);
    
    user.setAccount(account);
    
    return user;
    
}

@GetMapping("/all-users")
public List<User> getAllUsers(){
    return this.userService.getAllUsers();
}

@PostMapping("/add-user")
public ResponseEntity<Object> addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    try {
          User newUser = new User(user.getUserId(), user.getName(), user.getEmail());
          this.userService.addUser(newUser);
          return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          User newUser = new User(user.getUserId(), user.getName(), user.getEmail());
          return new ResponseEntity<>(newUser, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    
}
```

**getUser and getAllUsers are working fine (dont get confused by account in getUser that is my another microservice)**

When I am sending Post request using postman -

```
{
    "userId": 1314,
    "name": "James",
    "email": "james@gmail.com"
}
```

I am getting response -
500 Internal server error and User object which I wanted to check so I printed it out -

```
{
    "userId": 1314,
    "name": "Kavita Shrivastava",
    "email": "kavita@gmail.com",
    "account": null
}
```

I do not know why I am getting Internal server error.

**The request should add the new User to the list in UserServiceImpl.**

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace from the error?

Comment: @Sebastian https://filetransfer.io/data-package/iDvzEIpi#link here is the stacktrace

Comment: UserList is immutable under `UserServiceImpl`. Create list using `new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack trace has all the information you are looking for. `UserServiceImple.addUser` tries to add an object to the `userList` . but `userList` is an immutable list. so it throws exception. code flows to "catch" block and it returns 500 with newly created object.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion That's happens because
when U use List.of it equals to
**Collections.unmodifiableList** so it will throw an exception as Its Immutable.